# Cross-referencing DT::datatable in bookdown

Tags: r-markdown, knitr, dt, bookdown

I am trying to create a reference to `DT::datatable` in a bookdown project.

The bookdown manual states that `(\#tab:label)` should be placed at the beginning of the table caption. For testing, I created a new bookdown project in R-studio but replaced the contents of `_output.yml` with the following `html_book` configuration (I am only interested in HTML output).

```
bookdown::html_book:
    toc: yes
    theme: null
    highlight: pygments
    split_by: none
```

Then I added the following code at the bottom of `01-intro.Rmd`.

````
```{r irisTab}
DT::datatable(iris, caption = '(\\#tab:irisTab) Iris table')
```

See Table \@ref(tab:irisTab).
````

My expectation was that `(\\#tab:irisTab)` would be replaced by `Table 2.2` or at least `2.2` and the reference below would be `2.2`. However, this does not work. The label remains verbatim and the reference is `??`.

The closest I could get was by placing the caption text before the table.

````
Table (\#tab:irisTab): Iris table

```{r irisTab}
DT::datatable(iris)
```

See Table \@ref(tab:irisTab).
````

In that case, the reference works but the label `(\#tab:irisTab)` remains verbatim in the output, i.e. it is not replaced with `2.2` as expected.

Is there any way to create a DT table that would have a caption and could be referenced?

Update 1: @mikey-harper suggested using `fig.cap`. However, `fig.cap` updates only the `fig` counter and not the `tab` counter. Thus, if you have any non-DT tables, there will be multiple tables with the same number. It might be possible to treat all tables as figures. However, that would not be a standard approach. Typically, tables and figures have separate counters.

Answer (score 4):

> This issue has already been reported on GitHub: https://github.com/rstudio/bookdown/issues/313

Creating a `Table` caption for a `DT:datatable` within bookdown is not directly possible.

**Explanation**

HTML widgets like `DT:datatable` behave differently to the `knitr:kable` command which is typically used to create tables in bookdown. The `Table` caption will only be produced for a `kable` produced table, whilst all images/graphs/html outputs like this will not be labels as a table but as `Figure`.

**Additional Problem**

You are, however, also missing a key requirement for cross referencing, [as explained here](https://bookdown.org/yihui/bookdown/tables.html#tables):

> *"Like figures, tables with captions will also be numbered and can be referenced."*

**Workaround**

The best workaround is to treat the table as a figure, add a `fig.cap` to the chunk header and refer to it using `\@ref(fig:chunk-name)`:

````
---
title: "Untitled"
output: bookdown::html_book
---

Table \@ref(fig:irisTab): Iris table

```{r irisTab, fig.cap="A table"}
DT::datatable(iris)
```
````

[image]

> You will see this approach used in the **bookdown** book here by the package author: https://bookdown.org/yihui/bookdown/html-widgets.html. If it is good enough for Yihui, it is good enough for me.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. The problem with this approach is that it treats DT tables as figures, i.e. fig.cap updates the fig counter rather than the tab counter. I updated the question to relfect this problem.

Comment: Edited the answer to make it clearer that what you desire is not directly possible. If you display all your tables using DT then you will have a single list of Figures.

Answer (score 3):

Since the last answer here in StackOverflow the [GitHub Issue thread](https://github.com/rstudio/bookdown/issues/313) has continued and a [solution](https://github.com/rstudio/bookdown/issues/313#issuecomment-444161188) which is useful - at least to me in `bookdown::html_document2` - has emerged. For the sake of simplicity I will reproduce it here but it was [ldecicco-USGS](https://github.com/ldecicco-USGS) who originally wrote the chunk.

```yaml
---
title: "Untitled"
site: bookdown::bookdown_site
output: bookdown::gitbook
documentclass: book
---
```

````
```{r myDThtmltools, results="asis", echo=FALSE}
library(DT)

datatable(head(iris))
    
cat("<table>", paste0("<caption>",
                      "(#tab:myDThtmltools)",
                      "caption",
                      "Here's my caption",
                      "</caption>"),
                      "</table>", sep ="\n")
```
````

```
Tab. \@ref(tab:myDThtmltools)
```